# Calculating specific sides/edges of polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, calculate

I've a large dataset with different polygons totaling on 2372460 m2. I'm interesting in calculating the sides (in m1) of certain categories of polygons.

A case would be the sides of a form of green-polygon (gras, plants, bamboo, etc.) adjacent to any road-polygon (highway, local roads, etc.). The plants on the side of the road need to be cut, and therefore I'm interested in knowing the m1 of these sides. See an example below:

[image]

How would one go about calculating these sides, automatically, of all relevant polygons?

Comment: I think "perimeter" is the term you need here, perhaps to find the functionality, but also for others to find this question.

Comment: Thank you Mark, you are correct in that it is a part of the perimeter (part of the 'add geometry' function). I'm interested in the part of the perimeter that is adjacent to another specific polygon.

Comment: Ah, got it now. That makes it even more interesting.

Comment: How do you define which sides should be calculated? You want the total length of all red-yellow polygons? Or do you have some rules, like the yellow with ID 2,3,4?

Comment: Hi BERA, I think I have to re-classify the different types of attributes I already have (grass, plants, small trees, paved road, tiled road, etc.). Does that answer your question?